# slider revolution video background

Tags: wordpress, video, slider

I have a specific problem with the Slider Revolution video background.

I will try to explain:

I have a background video (hosted on vimeo premium), and a placeholder image that appears on mobile few seconds before video loads.

The problem is next: 
When a user visits the site, the user sees a placeholder image first, followed by 1-2 seconds of video, and later appears black screen for maybe 1-2 seconds and after all this the whole video appears.

I have checked the official Slider Revolution site, and it seems that even they have this issue. 
https://revolution.themepunch.com/wordpress-hero-vimeo/

I wanted to write to their support, but I need to renew it before asking questions, so I wanted to check here if anybody else had this kind of problem.

Is there any way to fix this, so the video loads immediately?

Thank you a lot, 
Vladimir

Comment: Did you try... (1) Use a direct link to an MP4 file saved in your webspace (Vimeo hosting might be the problem)... (2) Make your own video bg by using CSS layers. Layer 1 (bottom) holds `<video tag>` and layer 2 holds content (could be i-Frame loading another html of main content above video's layer).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link so I can look at the CSS? You can customize the transition to be zero.

**In the Settings:**

Go to layers timing & sorting for that slide *and select the* **"-" icon**> open the Layer Animation > Select fade out and enter 0 ms> click on "Custom Animation"> set the opacity to 100%> save changes> Save As> Save As New> Then Update Slide.

Comment: There is no transition, only this one slide exists on the website, so this solution doesn't work...